# Docusign APi Workflow

Tags: docusignapi, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I am new to Docusign. We are exploring if DocuSign can be integrated with Oracle Applications R12 iExpense Approval Workflow. I found API documents to send a document for signature. But, I would like to get a call to my webservice when the document is signed to reinstate workflow in Oracle Applications. I understand, there is a way to add an email in sequence to send the completed document. However, please let me know if there is any way for Docusign to call a Webservice or REST service when a document is signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three (3) general methods the DocuSign platform offers for getting real-time status of your documents and signature requests.

1. Poll the DocuSign platform for real-time envelope or recipient status.
2. Use the `eventNotification` property that's part of the envelope definition to configure a webhook for that given envelope.
3. Use the `DocuSign Connect` module to configure web hooks account wide, not just for a given envelope.

For #1, you can make REST or SOAP API calls to poll for real-time status.  However note that there are certain rate limits in place for polling (i.e. you can't poll the same envelope for status more than once every 15 mins).  See the Go Live section of the dev center to learn more about requirements in the production environment.

For #2, you can use the `eventNotification` object to configure your external URL (where you want events and data to be pushed to) along with security settings and other options.  This configures certain events or recipients for the envelope in question that you configure it for.  See the [webhook recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) for example code. The recipe includes a Heroku button so you can quickly try out the recipe. Search the API docs for "eventNotification" to learn more.

For #3, you can use the "DocuSign Connect" module to push events and data out to your app just like #2, however DocuSign Connect can be configured across the account as opposed to for just one given envelope.  You can filter by recipient, event type (i.e. signed, declined to sign, etc) and you can optionally include the signed documents in the request if you like.  See the DocuSign Connect section of the Dev Center to learn more.

[DocuSign Dev Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center)

Comment: I've added info on the webhook recipe for option #2. Also note that option #2 is available for all API integrations. Options 2 and 3 are far far superior to option 1.